# Is there any way to use <br> in laravel blade?

Tags: php, html, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

Im using laravel blade, in my variable im having an address with 
for example:

```
$footer->address = 'SHARJAH, <br> UAE';
```

why line break is not working? I already tried 
 &

Comment: `{!! $footer->address !!}`

Comment: Where is your blade template code? {{ $footer->address }} is escaped, you can use {!! $footer->address !!}

Comment: Please share more details, like the templating code involved. Also, please share what the current code prints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blade template, you probably need to use a different syntax so blade will render unescaped strings.

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

```
{!! $footer->address !!}
```

Comment: Just a thought -- why we used single bracket instead of double bracket for this?

Comment: I think it's just a different syntax that was chosen to represent unescaped content.

You can also change this syntax by doing something like this:

Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[', ']]');

Blade::setContentTags('[[[', ']]]');

Answer (score 0):

if you use this:

```
{!! $footer->address !!}
```

> 'SHARJAH, <br> UAE'

will be render.